# Find a power series that will converge to F(x)

Tags: taylor-expansion

The question is:
Find a power series that will converge to $F(x) = \int_0^x\sin(t^2)\;dt$.

I don't really have any idea how to solve this, but I know that I need to create the Maclaurin expansion so I can turn it into a series, but I am not really sure how to start. Do I need to find $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, ...? If so, what would be the derivative of this integral?

Comment: That's a good way to go. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if you really want to work it out term by term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write down the Maclaurin series $u-\frac{u^3}{3!}+\frac{u^5}{5!}-\frac{u^7}{7!}+\cdots$ for $\sin u$.
2. Replace $u$ everywhere by $t^2$.
3. Integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$.

**Remark:** It is not hard to find $F(0)$, $F'(0)$, and $F''(0)$. But higher derivatives are not pleasant to calculate.

Comment: This helps! thanks man.

Comment: You are welcome. After one has acquired a basic stock of Maclaurin series, further series are often obtained by algebraic manipulation and/or term by term differentiation, integration of known series.